# Find a string value on a webpage with swift

Tags: swift, web-scraping

I want to pull the balance value from a website: https://nimiq.watch/#NQ74+FLQL+DRE3+99PF+CET0+3N7D+JKLF+MQP6+87KS

The number after hash is the wallet address

I tried to use this to find the balance

```
wallet_address = "NQ48+8CKH+BA24+2VR3+N249+N8MN+J5XX+74DB+5XJ8"
let myURLString = "https://nimiq.watch/#"+wallet_address
let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString)
var myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL! as URL)
print(myHTMLString)
```

when I inspect element in browser it shows this..

```
<span>340510.29275 NIM</span>
```

But when I pull with the script I get this

```
<span>{%=_formatBalance(Nimiq.Policy.satoshisToCoins(o.balance))%} NIM</span>
```

any suggestions? or is this just not possible.. thanks!

Comment: The content is probably generated by javascript or similar

Comment: I see so it can’t be scraped?

Comment: I think it can but I am not an expert, I just started to look into this myself actually. [This GitHub project](https://github.com/cweatureapps/SwiftScraper) might be worth looking into.